# is Version.setArchived() method in Jira 7 API?

Tags: api, jira

In my Jira scripts I am using `setArchived()` (and other set methods) from Version class. In [Jira 6 API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/6.3.8/com/atlassian/jira/project/version/Version.html) the method exists and everything is fine. Now we are upgrading to Jira 7 and I can't find the method in [the latest Jira API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/project/version/Version.html). Has it been deprecated and removed? What to use instead of `Version.setArchived()`?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Since Jira v7 the Version interface is immutable. Need to use VersionManager interface instead, i.e. `VersionManager.archiveVersion()`.